# postgresql - use just created identity value to return newly inserted row

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

Using SQL Server I can write the following statement...

```
create table Person(
    id int identity(1,1),
    name varchar(50)
)

insert into Person(name) values ('John')
select * from Person where id = scope_identity()
```

In Postgres I can do this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.Person
(
  id serial primary key,
  name character varying(10) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Person(name) VALUES ('Smith', 'John') RETURNING id;
```

How would I write an equivalent statement like I did in the SQL example where don't return the id, but the entire row that was just inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO Person (name) VALUES ('Smith John'); 
select * from Person where id = currval('person_id_seq');
```

Comment: `lastval()` is another alternative. That way you don't need to know the sequence name

Answer (score 2):

As @cur4so stated, or alternatively

```
INSERT INTO Person(name) VALUES ('Smith', 'John') RETURNING *;
```